# How to give color for tick-lables on selection in Bootstrap slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-slider

I have a Bootstrap slider with ticks and tick labels,here I need to change the color of tick labels when I clicked on the particular label.

The below plunker link shows the code that I tried:

http://embed.plnkr.co/patfGe/

Comment: So you want us to just code it for you`*?

Comment: only for 100 or for all?

Comment: @Sagar V  for all,based on which label I clicked,it has to change color.

Comment: your image is not matching with your requirements. Can you be more specific. if you click on 100, 100 will be red. if you chose something else, it would be red and 100 will be black. right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.slider-tick-label').click(function(){
  $('.slider-tick-label').css('color','black');
  $(this).css('color','lightblue');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much